# Interact iPhone with tvOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, chat, tvos

I need to use an iPhone/iPad as keyboard for chat app.
Does anybody know how to interact iPhone with tvOS? I've not found some library or framework for this functionality.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you're looking for directly updates you can look into `Bonjour`:
https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/

You can also use Bonjour to use your phone as a Game controller (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17417)

I normally use `MultipeerConnectivity` for communication between devices, but this isn't available on `tvOS`.

For simple key value sharing, you can simply use the Keychain or NSUserDefaults, which is available on tvOS and shared between platforms.

Comment: Update: MultipeerConnectivity is available in tvOS 10+: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity